# Connecting to Bitbucket using ssh through proxy

Tags: proxy

I have run out of options. I have tried several methods but none have worked so I hope someone can help me.

At work we operate behind a proxy; at the moment I am setting a repository that I would like to pull from and push from. I want to this using ssh so I don't need the password at work or when I take the laptop at home.

The repository is created.
I have created an additional distinct ssh key and added it in bitbucket setting profile.
I have loaded the ssh key using the following command - ssh-add ~/.ssh/personal
I have checked and the key is loaded.

when I try to connect to my repository,using clone or any other action(push or pull),it doesn't work

operation timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

I have also tried to create a config file in .ssh/ with the following values

Host personalid
 HostName bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personal

but still it doesn't work

I don't know whether is a proxy issue or something else, I thought ssh should allow me to bypass everything.

Can someone give me an idea on how to diagnose the problem?

Thank you

=========

UPDATE: result of the command ssh -Tv hg@bitbucket.org

```
   ssh -Tv hg@bitbucket.org
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/username/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [131.103.20.167] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 131.103.20.167 port 22: Operation timed out
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [131.103.20.168] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 131.103.20.168 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Operation timed out

=========

If i use port 443

ssh -Tv -p 443 hg@bitbucket.org
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/username/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [131.103.20.167] port 443.
debug1: connect to address 131.103.20.167 port 443: Operation timed out
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [131.103.20.168] port 443.
debug1: connect to address 131.103.20.168 port 443: Operation timed out
```

## ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 443: Operation timed out

```
when trying ssh -Tvp443 hg@altssh.bitbucket.or
ssh -Tvp443 hg@altssh.bitbucket.org
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/username/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to altssh.bitbucket.org [131.103.20.174] port 443.
debug1: connect to address 131.103.20.174 port 443: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host altssh.bitbucket.org port 443: Operation timed out
```

Comment: Hey man, how far did you eventually get with this? I'm having the same problem, I feel like I'm almost there but giving up because I'm getting a stupid error that I can't figure out. What I've found might help you though. First there's this git config: https://gist.github.com/daicham/10253947 The `connect.exe` referenced on the first line is also mentioned and can be downloaded in this other helpful article: http://www.returnbooleantrue.com/2009/06/using-github-through-draconian-proxies.html. Hopefully this helps someone at least.

Answer (score 0):

The best diagnosis would be to fake an SSH session:

```
ssh -Tv hg@bitbucket.org
```

(It doesn't matter whether you're using Git or Mercurial; this test does the same thing either way.)

There'll be a wall of output from the command, thanks to the -v, but the first thing to look for would be a line like this at the end with your specific username:

```
logged in as cpu2007.
```

That will establish that a) you're reaching Bitbucket and b) your key is added to your account. If you don't see a line like that, then that should help you diagnose your problem.

Comment: I have tested those commands before but no luck. I am behind a proxy and I need to know how to work around that proxy but don't know how to set it.

Comment: What happens if you try `ssh -Tvp443 hg@altssh.bitbucket.org`?